# Emacs Lisp and non-deterministic regexes

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I've been spending too much time lately trying to debug some auto-complete-mode functionality in Emacs, this function appears to be non-deterministic and has left me utterly confused.

```
 (re-search-backward "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\|\\s\\.\\|\\s\\\\|[#@|]\\)\\=")
```

The command is called in a while loop, searching backwards from the current point to find the full "word" that should be autocompleted. For reference, [the actual code](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/e489a3019bf12ac930d32f900e408d4e7977d028/slime.el#L7604-7611).

#### A bit of background and my investigations

I have been trying to setup autocompletion for Javascript, using slime to connect to a Node.js backend.

Autocomplete inside a Slime REPL connected to a Node.js backend is perfect,

[image]

Autocomplete inside a js2-mode buffer, connected to Slime, is failing to look up completions from slime. In this image you can see it falling back to the words already in the buffer.

[image]

I've tracked this down to Slime's [slime-beginning-of-symbol](https://github.com/slime/slime/blob/e489a3019bf12ac930d32f900e408d4e7977d028/slime.el#L7604-7611) function.

Assume that I'm trying to complete `fs.ch` where `fs` has been required and is in scope already, the point is located on after the `h` character.

In the slime repl buffer the beginning function moves the point all of the way back until it hits whitespace and matches `fs.ch`.

In the js2-mode buffer the beginning function moves the point only to the dot character and matches only `ch`.

#### Reproducing the problem

I've been testing this by `eval`ing `(re-search-backward "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\|\\s\\.\\|\\s\\\\|[#@|]\\)\\=")` repeatedly in various buffers. For all examples, the point starts at the end of the line and moves backwards until the search fails.

- In the scratch buffer `fs.ch` the point ends on the `c`.
- In the slime repl `fs.ch` the point ends on the `f`.
- In the js2-mode buffer `fs.ch` the point ends on the `c`.
- In an emacs-lisp-mode buffer `fs.ch` the point ends on the `f`.

#### I have no idea why this is happening

I'm going to assume that there's something in these modes that either sets or unsets a global regex var that then has this effect, but so far I've been unable to find or implicate anything.

I even tracked this down to the [emacs c code](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/b2b5f414358a7835b56613f67d2b0278ee804290/src/search.c#L2128), but at that point realised that I was in completely over my head and decided to ask for help.

#### Help?

Comment: `\sCODE` in an Emacs regexp matches any character whose syntax is `CODE`. Syntax tables can and will vary between buffers (the syntax table is typically established by the major mode). See `C-h i g (elisp) Regexp Backslash RET`

Comment: I think your problem is that `.` has a different syntax in these buffers. You could check with `M-x describe-syntax` in the respective buffer. Maybe, you need `modify-syntax-entry` to correct this. Maybe, you need a temporary syntax-table created with `make-syntax-table` which inherits the standard for the major mode.

Comment: That's exactly it. I raised the question in #emacs and they said the same. I didn't know about the syntax tables before now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" the problem by redefining the source that gets added to auto complete's `ac-sources`.

I'm still learning my way around elisp so this is likely the most hack-like way of achieving what I need, but it works.

I changed the regex from:

```
\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\|\\s\\.\\|\\s\\\\|[#@|]\\)\\=
```

to

```
\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\|\\s.\\|\\s\\\\|[#@|]\\)\\=
```

(note the change of `\\s\\.\\` to `\\s.\\`).

And then overrode the auto-complete setup in my init.el. (I'll probably find a hundred ways to refine this when I actually know elisp).

```
(defun js-slime-beginning-of-symbol ()
  "Move to the beginning of the CL-style symbol at point."
  (while (re-search-backward "\\(\\sw\\|\\s_\\|\\s.\\|\\s\\\\|[#@|]\\)\\="
                             (when (> (point) 2000) (- (point) 2000))
                             t))
  (re-search-forward "\\=#[-+.<|]" nil t)
  (when (and (looking-at "@") (eq (char-before) ?\,))
    (forward-char)))

(defun js-slime-symbol-start-pos ()
  "Return the starting position of the symbol under point.
The result is unspecified if there isn't a symbol under the point."
  (save-excursion (js-slime-beginning-of-symbol) (point)))

(defvar ac-js-source-slime-simple
  '((init . ac-slime-init)
    (candidates . ac-source-slime-simple-candidates)
    (candidate-face . ac-slime-menu-face)
    (selection-face . ac-slime-selection-face)
    (prefix . js-slime-symbol-start-pos)
    (symbol . "l")
    (document . ac-slime-documentation)
    (match . ac-source-slime-case-correcting-completions))
  "Source for slime completion.")

(defun set-up-slime-js-ac (&optional fuzzy)
  "Add an optionally-fuzzy slime completion source to `ac-sources'."
  (interactive)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources ac-js-source-slime-simple))
```

In response to my own question about regex global state. There is a lot of it.

Emacs regexes use syntax tables defined in the major mode to determine which characters to match. The reason I was seeing the dot match in the lisp mode but not the js mode was because of different definitions. In the lisp mode '.' is defined as symbol, in js2-mode '.' is defined as punctuation.

As a consequence, an alternative way to fix the problem is to redefine .'s syntax in js2-mode. I tried this out and redefined . as a word with `(modify-syntax-entry ?. "w")`. However I decided not to stay with that result because it will probably break something down the line.

Also, I have to thank the people in #emacs, they really helped me out on this, teaching me about syntax tables and the horrors of elisp regex globals.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `\\s\\.` with `\\s.` in your regexp.